# Is it best to define a variable when using the same $_GET key multiple times?

Tags: php

In multiple place on a script I have ...

```
if (isset($_GET['event-id']) { ... }
```

Would it slow things down to call the key twice? Should I just define a new var like ...

```
$event_id = $_GET['event-id'];
if ($event_id) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This also raise an `E_NOTICE` if `$_GET['event-id']` is not set:

```
$event_id = $_GET['event-id'];
```

I prefer

```
$event_id = isset($_GET['event-id']) ? $_GET['event-id'] : false;
```

especially when I am going to use `$event_id` multiple times. Then, I can write:

```
if($event_id){
 //do your code
}
```

or in cases that an empty `$event_id` is possible:

```
if($event_id !== false){
 //do your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always go with second approach

```
$event_id = $_GET['event-id'];
if ($event_id) { ... }
```

It will not slow things but suppose in the future 'event-id' changes then you will have to change it every where which will be a heavy task to do.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to assign this onto a var and validate it before all further processing, to get sure this var contains no prohibited content.

I don't think it would slow down as it's only a Array call, but it is a security gap.

Edit:

Also if it isn't set you could define a default value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is really a need to check `$_GET['event-id']` at many places in your code, you can set it once using [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$event_id = isset($_GET['event-id']) ? $_GET['event-id'] : '' ;
```

Then you can use it like `if ($event_id)` or `if(empty($event_id))` or `if(!empty($event_id))` depending upon your need of condition.